# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello_world.ko: Operation not permitted

Tags: drivers

I have created an simple hello_world.c file and related make file but whenever I am doing insmod it is throwing me an error. Please help me out.
I am using ubuntu 18.04  LTS.

[hello_world.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmymk.png)

**Makefile:**
[Makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUYls.png)

After doing *sudo make* and by doing *ls* I can see the below files:

[List fo files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrtyA.png)

After this if I do *sudo insmod hello_world.ko* then I am getting:

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello_world.ko: Operation not permitted

Comment: Why would you want "hello world" to be a kernel module?

Comment: For testing purposes. I am practicing myself so want to test the module.